# DateTime Object - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, datetime, object

When I `print_r` my array, it shows a series of Date Objects like below:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2011-11-08 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2011-11-17 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

... etc, etc

But when I try to echo it out, I hit a 500 Error. What gives? I don't see any difference between

```
print_r($row[$x]['OrderDate']);
```

and

```
echo '<td>' . $row[$x]['OrderDate'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Put this in the top of the script and tell us what the error is:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: It doesn't appear that the DateTime class has a toString method: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: print_r is a function that prints information about a variable in human readable format...echo is a language construct not a function. The data provided to echo must make some sense. The $row[$x]['OrderDate'] is not a String yet you are trying to use the string concatenation operator with it.

Comment: Daan, sorry...how do I accept answers? I get a lot of good ones. Oops...nevermind -- I figured out how. So do you want me to go back to my previous questions and flag all of the solutions I used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $row[$x]['OrderDate']->format('m-d-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td>' . date('Y-m-d', $row[$x]['OrderDate'] . '</td>'
```